# How to rewrite default php code to a valid echo line output?

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, echo

I am new to PHP and for the development of a Wordpress theme I need to re-write the following line of php/html code so that I can use it in my functions.php.
I found out that I would need to rewrite it as an "echo" call, but I am always getting an error because my syntax is wrong.

This is the line we're talking about:

```
<div <?php post_class( 'brick_item ' . $termString ) ?> onclick="location.href='<?php the_permalink(); ?>'">
```

I've tried several times, e.g.

```
echo '<div class="'. post_class("brick_item" . $termString); .'" onclick=location.href="'. the_permalink() .'">';
```

but I am doing something wrong in encapsulating things I guess.

EDIT:
As requested, the part of the functions.php

```
    function get_latest_posts() {
        
        echo '<div class="latest-posts">';
            echo '<div class="brick_list">';

                $args = array(
                    post_type => 'post',
                    cat => '-3,-10',
                    posts_per_page => 3
                );

                $latestposts_query = new WP_Query($args);

                if ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $latestposts_query->have_posts() ) : $latestposts_query->the_post(); 
                    
                    echo '<div '. post_class( $termString ) .' onclick=location.href='. the_permalink() .'>';

                endwhile; else :

                    get_template_part('template_parts/content','error');

                endif; 
                wp_reset_postdata();

            echo '</div>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
    add_shortcode( 'get_latest_posts', 'get_latest_posts' );
```

Comment: Can you put the part of the functions.php file where this is going?

Comment: I have edited my code sample and added the part from the functions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a semicolon in the middle of your line

`echo '<div class="'. post_class("brick_item" . $termString);`  `.'" onclick=location.href="'. the_permalink() .'">';`

should be

`echo '<div class="'. post_class("brick_item" . $termString) .'" onclick=location.href="'. the_permalink() .'">';`

semicolons signify end of line in php, thus your code did first execute

`echo '<div class="'. post_class("brick_item" . $termString);`

which is fine, but only half of what you want.
Then php tries executing

`.'" onclick=location.href="'. the_permalink() .'">';`

but doesn't know what to do with a dot at the start of the line. Dot means append string before to string after, but there is nothing before, so it's a compile error.
You can also just add another echo to the second line instead of the dot

`echo '" onclick=location.href="'. the_permalink() .'">';`

Comment: thank you for your great explanation! It did help me enough to get my problem solved! I wasn't aware that I could write the code in multiple lines that easy. Now it works as expected, thatnk you so much. Will never forget this "tweak" ;-) Greetings from Basel to Bonn and have a nice evening!

Answer (score 1):

Let's see where this gets us as I've cleaned up the code a bit. The `div` would just be hanging out there so I put the permalink in it.

```php
function get_latest_posts() {

    echo '<div class="latest-posts">';
    echo '<div class="brick_list">';

    $args = array(
        post_type => 'post',
        cat => '-3,-10',
        posts_per_page => 3
    );

    $latestposts_query = new WP_Query($args);
    
    if($latestposts_query->have_posts()) {
      while($latestposts_query->have_posts()) {
        $thePost = $latestposts_query->the_post();
        echo '<div ' . post_class($thePost) . ' onclick="location.href=\'' . the_permalink() . '\'">' . the_permalink() . '</div>';
      }
    } else {
        get_template_part('template_parts/content','error');
    }

    wp_reset_postdata();

    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'get_latest_posts', 'get_latest_posts' );
```

Comment: this has the div with class="brick_list" and directly behind is the post_class in no mans land. "class="post-55 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-knowledge-transfer tag-awareness-day tag-nephrology"http://localhost/knowledge-transfer/test-post-3/http://localhost/knowledge-transfer/test-post-3/"  
After this follows the div where I wanted to have the post_class for. 
<div onclick="location.href=''"></div>

Comment: Can you post what output you see in HTML in a comment? Put the backticks so that it formats it correctly